# Property 'isMarkedAsAnswered' not found on object of type 'GameData'

Tags: xcode, methods, parameters, autocomplete

I am new to obj C, and coming from a very good C++ background. I started iOS dev, and made a custom object which I use in a View.
This Custom object is

```
    @interface GameData : NSObject{
    @private
        int Lives;
        ...
        bool isAnswered[5];
    };

    -(int)getLives;
    -(void)LivesPlusOne;
    ...
    -(void)increasePoints:(int)howManyPoints ;
    -(int)getMult;
    ...
    -(void)markAsAnswered:(int)idToRemove; //idToRemove is marked as answered
    -(bool)isMarkedAsAnswered:(int)idToCheck;
    @end
```

My Problem is that, although XCode recognizes and autocompletes methods like gameData.getLives; and compiles them just OK ( i use #import "GameData.h" ), it does not for methods with a parameter,like:

```
    -(bool)isMarkedAsAnswered:(int)idToCheck;
```

which might be the problem? (I already tried deleting derived data (window->organizer->projects->derived data->delete) and nothing changed.

Extra info: I am using the gameData object in a View and i manipulate the "int Lives"ect, via accessors and mutators (getters/setters) and works really fine. When I get to use

```
    [gameData.isMarkedAsAnswered:someInt]
```

I get a build error.

it does not even autocomplete when I type

```
    [gamedata.i
```

Thanks in Advance,
Giorgos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[gameData.isMarkedAsAnswered:someInt]
```

You're mixing up C++ and Objective-C syntax.  You use the dot accessor to refer to declared properties, not methods.  Use the following:

```
[gameData isMarkedAsAnswered:someInt];
```

Due to implementation issues, when a method has no arguments, you can call it using the dot accessor, however this is not what it was designed for and you should stop doing so immediately.